# Is it possible to launch an external binary app from erlang node?

Tags: c, erlang

I want for launch some program from erlang node, transfer some data to its standard input and read stdout, when it's done. Is it possible?

Yes I now about C-nodes, but I don't want to rewrite my binary app.

Comment: Is os:cmd (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#cmd-1) enough for you?

Comment: Is it possible to pass smth on stdin?

Comment: os:cmd("ls -l | wc -l").

Answer (score 2):

I use open_port:

```
run (Cmd, Params, State, Stage, PrevStage) ->
  Shell = Cmd ++ " " ++ binary_to_list (Params) ++ " 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null",
  io:format ("try to run: ~p~n", [Shell]),
  Port = open_port ({spawn, Shell}, [exit_status]),
```